# Is it possible to inject HTML into a div through external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webpack

I am trying to build a html component which will have a text box where user will come and enter something. A button which will post textbox data to server & a grid component which will show all the data user have posted so far.

I want to put all these components over a sliding menu [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push).

The trick part is, I want this component to be used by multiple web applications. What I am trying to do is, I will ask the consuming apps to just add a `<div> tab with some specific id` (like this) and a reference to a JavaScript file & a CSS file (which I will bundle)

Inside this div, I want to inject HTML code (textbox, button and grid) through JavaScript. is it possible to first put HTML code inside a JS file and the inject that HTML code on page load over a div ?

Comment: I think I understand your question but have you heard of CDNs?  There's no difference between an end user referencing their scripts or your scripts.  Your javascript would just accomplish this with something like  `document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML = '<div>Your Html</div>';`

Comment: @lamelemon: My question is more towards, how to package my html into a bundle (a js file) & then after referencing this bundle either directly or though CDN, how do I extract that HTML again to do something like this `document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML = '<div>Your Html</div>'`

Comment: Just add your HTML to a variable like this: `var html = '<div class="abc">Hello World</div>';`.

Comment: You should look at creating jquery plugins...